# Using a ReactJS prop as the validator in Redux Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux-form

How do I tell react to take `constraints` from a prop passed to`LoginForm` from its parent?

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'LoginForm',
  validate: formValidator(constraints)
})(LoginForm)
```

In the above working code, constraints is not declared outside of the React components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`validate` can be passed to the form as a prop instead of the `reduxForm` config. So you'd pass it when you instantiate:

`<LoginForm validate={formValidator(constraints)} />`

http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/